# Textbox losing value after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page is a registration page, where a user enters an e-mail address and password. Here is my click event:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;

    MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(txtUsername.Text,
        txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text, null, null, true, out createStatus);

    if (createStatus != MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
        cvUser.IsValid = false;
        cvUser.ErrorMessage = "Invalid";
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("Home");
}
```

Here is my page:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />

<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvUser" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
```

`cvUser` is a custom validator on my page that I'm using so that the error message will show up on my `ValidationSummary`.

So the problem occurs when the user creation fails. I set `cvUser.IsValid` to false so that the error will show, and then the page reloads. Only when the page reloads, all the data in my textboxes is gone.

Is there a way to maintain that data?

Comment: Do you have any code running to create controls on the page? How are the textboxes added to the page? In the ASPX or the code behind?

Comment: I would expect that you are doing something in a Page_Load/Init/PreRender/Render that should be wrapped in `!Page.IsPostBack`

Comment: You need to show your initialization events, as J Torres suggested, you are probably erasing it there.

Comment: @JayS - My controls are on the page, and I have nothing in my Page_Load event

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence: `the error will show, and then the page reloads` the most interesting part is how the page reloads

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy - the page posts back because I don't do anything if the user creation fails. If it succeeds, I redirect away. If it fails, I set the custom validator valid attribute to false, and then it displays when the page reloads

Answer (score 0):

After a post back, it is necessary to either manually re-populate the form items, or to ensure that their values are not overwritten. The latter can be accomplished by placing any form population code in the Page_Load method, but wrapped in a if (!IsPostBack) {} block.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  //populate form items
}
else //this is a post back
{
  //do nothing
}
```